# use ngxtop to filter by particular date

Tags: nginx, logging, server, monitoring

I'm using ngxtop for nginx log monitoring.

```
ngxtop --no-follow
```

This outputs request counts for all the data in the access log.
I'm just interested in request counts of a day before the current date.

Is there a way i can output request counts for a particular date?

Answer (score 1):

nxtop uses Python for its filter flag (`-i`).

The variable names used are those of http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

So you can filter by date like this:

`ngxtop --no-follow -i 'time_local > "12/Jan/2018:20:00:00"' print remote_addr time_local request`

Note, multiple filter need to be specified via a python expression, not multiple `-i` flags, e.g.
`-i 'time_local > "12/Jan/2018:00:00:00"' and time_local < "20/Jan/2018:00:00:00"`.